# Probability about random variables with exponential distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $n$ batteries which has a lifetime that is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Each battery's lifetime is independent.

If we initially put 2 batteries on and every time a battery fails, we replace it with another battery until there is only one working battery.

What is the probability that we can use these $n$ more than $x$ years. And what is the expectation of the total time until there is only one battery left working.

---

I realize that we need to use the memoryless property of exponential distribution r.vs but I kind of got stuck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

The failure of the batteries is a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process)

Having two batteries on at the same time doubles the intensity of the process

You can use the $n$ batteries up to the point at which there have been $n-1$ failures

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about this? Can I simply assume that the process in the question can be modeled as a Gamma distribution random variable with parameter $(n-1,\lambda)$? @Henry

Comment: @John:You have to double the intensity, so the second parameter is $2\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

I believe whenever you change a battery, the remaining one just acts like it has been freshly changed too, according to the memoryless property. Thus the question can be simplified into: How long could $(n-1)$ batteries last.
Because batteries' lifespan are all idd, the probability of their sum should be:
$$
P(x)=\int_0^\infty \cdots \int_0^{t_i} \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f(t_i-x)f(x)dx\,.
$$

Comment: Not quite - the distribution of failure times of a *pair* of batteries is the minimum of two exponential distributions with rate $\lambda$, which is another exponential with rate $2\lambda$.